# Do GUI text editors have a Samba share file size limit?

Tags: samba, editors

I cannot get Simple GUI text editors (`xed` or `gedit`) to open `.txt` files larger than 40 kb from a Samba share.

I have a Samba share set up on the USB port on a TP-Link router. I have connected this to two different Linux Mint systems (one Cinnamon and one Mate) with the same result.

- a 25 kB `TextFile.txt` will open in `xed` or `gedit` on Mint.
- a 40 kB `TextFile.txt` **will not** open in `xed` or `gedit` on Mint.

Error message is:

> Could not open the file smb://SHARE. Unexpected error: Broken pipe
> Terminal shows:

```
Hit unhandled case 44 (Broken pipe) in parse_error.
```

Further information:

- The file will open in `nano` (in the terminal)
- The file can be copied from the Share to Mint Desktop.
- The file will open in Libre Office on Mint.
- The file will open in notepad.exe on Windows.
- Restart, Remount changes nothing.
- `testparm` looks OK to me, but I have not looked into the various timeouts shown with `testparm -v`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There's no such limit I'm aware of. Question: What **exactly** are you doing to access the samba share? (I ask because this will provide pointers to the broken component, probably!)

Comment: by the way, this really sounds like a gvfs bug. When you say you can open it in nano, through which path are you accessing it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Nemo of Caja, type smb://SHARE_NAME in the address bar. I also went through the File > Connect to Server... process but I don't remember if that was successful. Once the share is mounted, I can access the directory through the terminal with cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SHARE_NAME,share=g From there I can open the file in nano. Except for the change of file manager, this is all the same on 2 different Linux Mint 21.3 systems.

Comment: Do you have any crash messages in `dmesg`, or any GVFS or libsmbclient error messages in `journalctl -b`? Can you `gio cat` the file's smb:// URL, or download it using `smbclient`? (All of this uses smbclient; I'm slightly curious whether a kernel SMB mount using `mount -t cifs` would have different results.) Honestly, my bets are on the router's SMB server crashing due to something like "out of memory".

Comment: @user1977596 but `gedit /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SHARE_NAME,share=g/filename` does work, right? And, can you really try with the "Connect to Server" method? Also, can you tell us what the MTU on the link to your router is (as found via `ip link`), please?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts'
I see nothing in the recent dmesg files that suggests a crash, but I could be missing something.

I opened journalctl -b and read the last entries.
Then I attempted to open the 40 GB text file (it failed), ran journalctl -b again and saw no change in the journalctl file.

gio cat opens the file in the terminal window.

Comment: $ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:25:a5:3e:e5:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:56:e5:af:25:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: I'm going to call this as solved although it is more of a work-around.
Logging into the router's server with ftp instead of smb allows long files to open normally in the text editors.
This does not explain how to get smb to do the same.
Thanks to Marcus Müller for his help.